# Probability of 5 dice throws adding up to 27

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem statement:
Five fair dice are tossed. What is the probability of getting a sum of 27?

This is my approach:
We have 3 different possible combinations:

$6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 3 = 27$

$6 + 6 + 6 + 5 + 4 = 27$

$6 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 27$

Adding up the permutations of these combinations:

$\frac{5!}{4!} + \frac{5!}{3!} + \frac{5!}{2!*3!} = 35$

$\frac{35}{6^5} = 0.0045$ which is the wrong answer according to my textbook.

If possible, please only give me a hint so I can still figure it out myself. Thank you!

Comment: I agree with your computation.  Possibly they wanted the answer expressed as a fraction?

Comment: What does your textbook say?

Comment: textbook says 0.0032 which is fairly close though. It's from a very known textbook from Saeed Ghahramani - Fundamentals-of-Probability with Stochastic Processes 4th edition.

Comment: Mistakes happen, even in first rate texts.

Comment: Book answer seems wrong and I won't say it is fairly close :)

Comment: Ill try email the author if I can find it. Im gonna check if there is a 5th edition first.

Comment: Or, you can try googling if there is known *errata* (i.e. list of errors) for your current edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your answer.

You can also do this in *Mathematica*:

```
    Probability[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 == 27, 
    # \[Distributed] DiscreteUniformDistribution[{1, 6}] & /@ 
   {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}]
```

(* 35/7776 *)

0.00450103

Comment: Weird...Textbooks says 0.0032 which is fairly close though. It's from a very known textbook from Saeed Ghahramani - Fundamentals-of-Probability with Stochastic Processes 4th edition.